# How to calculate execution time of Go concurrent function

Tags: go, concurrency

I want to calculate execution time of concurrent function( go routine) in golang.

I am using below code, but I think it's giving me wrong time.  As we know cpu is shared among go routines and go routines shuffle for execution as one routine can't occupy more time on cpu. I think my solution is incorrect. Please suggest right way. If my understanding is incorrect then also correct me.

```
func timeElapsed() func() {

   start := time.Now()

   return func() {

      timeElapsed := time.Since(start)

      fmt.Println("This function took", timeElapsed, "time")
   }
}

func thisIsGoFunction {

   defer timeElapsed()()

   //Some code which is doing some iterations over map and mutex
}
```

Comment: If you are trying to measure elapsed time it doesn’t matter whether your goroutine is running or not, the elapsed time is what it is. You are correct in a sense that elapsed time is kind of meaningless when there are a lot of goroutines sharing a single os thread and cpu

Answer (score 2):

This approach is good for measuring time of synchronous calls not for goroutines.

For concurrent functions execution time can be best calculated by using either benchmark tests with `cpuprofile` option, which produces cpu profile file that can be fed to pprof.

Or directly including pprof in code, run load, and then see the graph e.g. flame graph